How to measure the actual benefits of using @NaturalId in Hibernate?
I'm  using Hibernate/Spring Data came across the @NaturalId annotation. The documentation (Hibernate User Guide) suggests that @NaturalId can optimize queries and offers a dedicated API for loading entities by their natural ID.
However, I'm wondering how I can measure and prove these benefits in practice? For example, I noticed that @NaturalId doesn't affect the first-level cache, which only applies to the primary key (@Id). What are the real performance differences that I should expect to observe? Has anyone had experience comparing the performance of operations with and without @NaturalId?
I’m specifically interested in analyzing these benefits without involving second-level cache or the natural ID cache.
I'd appreciate any examples, tips, or best practices on how to monitor and measure these optimizations.
Thanks!
